# Redirect with nginx (remove substring from url)

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, redirect, ngx-http-rewrite-module

I want do a redirect from old url:

```
http://example.org/xxxxxxxxx.html
```

To new urls (remove ".html")

```
http://example.org/xxxxxxxxx
```

How I can do this with nginx?

**EDIT**:

`xxxxxxxxx` can be differ, example:

`http://example.org/url-1.html` redirect to `http://example.org/url-1`
`http://example.org/another-url.html` redirect `to http://example.org/another-url`

Comment: op, did my answer satisfy your question?  if yes, please upvote and accept!  if no, feel free to provide clarifications of where it falls short, if it does.

Comment: thanks for accept&&upvote, +1 your way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
location ~ ^(.*)\.html$ {
    return 301 $1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need a rewrite statement

```
location /xxx.html {
   rewrite ^/xxx(.*) http://example.org/xxxxx permanent;
 }
```

You detailed explanation please refer https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Another method would be return directive

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.old-name.com old-name.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.new-name.com;
}
```

Comment: @rpayanm try above methods in configuration and let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.org www.example.org;
    return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```