# Nginx remove substring and add as url param

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171713/redirect-with-nginx-remove-substring-from-url), but the answer did not work for me.

I need to turn this: `/api/batch.json?param=1`

into `/batch?param=1&format=json`

Nginx location:

```
location /api/batch {
   proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header   Host             $http_host;
   proxy_pass         http://localhost:8000/batch;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Indeed I lost `param-1`

Comment: That didn't want to work, so I've updated my post.

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/api(/batch)\.(json)$ $1?format=$2 break;` inside the `location` block.

Comment: Brilliant, works like a charm. You are welcome to post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rewrite...break` to change the URI within a `location` before passing it upstream using `proxy_pass`.

For example:

```
location /api/batch {
    ...
    rewrite ^/api(/batch)\.(json)$ $1?format=$2 break;
    proxy_pass  ...;
}
```

The `rewrite` directive will automatically append the original parameters (if any) unless the replacement string ends with a `?`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.